# What is the difference between ":" and "=" for default values of named arguments in class constructors and function arguments

Tags: dart

Consider an animal class, which has two fields - `totalLegs` and `type`.

```dart
class Animal {
  final int totalLegs;
  final String type;
}
```

Let's say that `totalLegs` defaults to 4 and `type` default to "cat". We can set the default values for the fields two different ways:

1. Using "="

```dart
class Animal {
  ...

  Animal({this.totalLegs = 4, this.type = 'cat'});
}
```

2. Using ":"

```dart
class Animal {
  ...

  Animal({this.totalLegs: 4, this.type: 'cat'});
}
```

Do both ways behave the same? What is the difference? Or, if there is no difference, why isn't there only one way to set default values?

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#do-use--to-separate-a-named-parameter-from-its-default-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same, but the `:` one was deprecated. It was replaced with `=`. I think the deprecated one wasn't removed for some backward compatibility reasons. But the `=` is now recommended to use instead of `:`, and the future of it is not assured. It could get removed in the future versions of Dart, or it won't.